# How to blend union type into partial type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Let's have the following type in TypeScript:

```
type Input = {
  a: string
  b: number
} | {
  c: string
}
```

What is the simplest way to blend it in a partial type:

```
type Result = {
  a?: string
  b?: number
  c?: string
}
```

Essentially, I am looking for a type `Blend<T>`:

```
type Blend<T> = ...
```

So, I can define `Result` as following:

```
type Result = Blend<Input>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transform union type to intersection type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I do not want to transform union type to intersection type. I want to get partial type. However, Aleksey uses the answer provided there in his solution.

Comment: But the answer you have accepted does exactly that :) with obvious additional step. It even links the question I have mentioned. So this is basically a dup.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Is it duplicated answer or duplicated question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [union to intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/1113002) wrapped with [Partial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype):

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> =
    (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never

type Blend<T> = Partial<UnionToIntersection<T>>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZwCpIJJ2BATgZwgGNhk4AeGAPigF4AoKJqAChiggA8c4ATfKAEM4IKAH5WAawBcsAJR0aANyQJeUWXAhK8Crj36sWMqAjgAzPFAwLay1bwUSMGqFp2569UJCgAhABsIPnJUGlooAAVBXFJBAMpEFHQsHAJiUhRQqiovH2gsMABXYDooAG9GZkFZfGBcMwBzKqYAI00igFtWvHoAXygAHwqWqCJa%20qb%20vPBoACUIfCKA0ojA4N5yQpLcoA)

Comment: Thank you, I have fixed the title.

Comment: Can you give a short explanation as to why you need the `UnionToIntersection` magic here? Wouldn't simply using `Partial` also work?

Comment: @tomcek112 you're right, in this specific example simple `Partial` would do. But technically it produces a union and if you'd like to do some further processing - it will remain union (not what requested by OP) https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdmArsKBeKBvAUFXUCGAXFAM7ABOAlnAOY54BGxciAtgxOVgL5QA+mergDGxMlVo8sWUJCgAlCCUQAbFOkUBHRJXIQAJgB4ACvnLBK+FYfhJgAPnvThAezhko5YouVq0mAmIAciCAGihRKCCARiCoXgB6BKg4FyhOchdyKEBeDcAEPawgA